# How do I make my followers leave me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently had the Amazing Follower Tweaks mod, and I uninstalled it while forgetting I already had a follower in-game. Basically what's happened is my follower, Marcurio, refuses to leave my service. He gives me the dialogue, and the game gives me a notification that my follower has left my service, but he still follows me around. I've even gone straight to the point and tried setting my follower count to 0 in the console, but that did absolutely nothing. I'd like to keep him, so I don't want to kill him, but is there another way I can force followers from my service?

The icing on the cake is that whenever I activate him, instead of saying good morning or one of his usual lines, he gives me a taunt from the Throw Voice shout.

EDIT: For those who were unsure, yes I shut down the game before removing said mod.

Comment: Well you could try to install the mod/mods again ... than send him home and uninstall the mods again :)

Comment: The only thing that can make skyrim buggier: mods.

Comment: You really should not remove mods from a running game. It makes skyrim unstable. Removing a mod does not remove all parts of the mod (there are some running scripts). Remove the mods, and start the game over. It is the only way that guarantees no corrupt saves in 200 hours playtime (And even that is not a guarantee).

Comment: Have you tried replacing him with another follower, then kicking them out?

Comment: Turning off the game when you remove mods does not prevent bugs. Starting a new game does. (You know, the moment you are captive). Do not remove mods and then load a game that needed those mods.

Comment: Jeez, you seem like a salty guy. Anyway, thanks everyone for your responses. I'll try tinkering around with the console and reinstalling some mods. Hope is not yet lost.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try.  If this is a mod follower and you have the creation kit you can try loading the mod file and removing the actor's follower factions, then he won't follow you.  And editing morality stats.  I had the same problem when I tried to force Delphine to be a follower - she wouldn't leave.

if you don't have creation kit you can open your console and try the following:

Select the follower and type:

setav aggression 1
setav confidence 3

might get him to stop attacking you.

You might try:
setav morality 1 or 0

Might make him ignore witnessed crimes.

set playerfollowercount to 0

You can also try (if you can figure out how, sorry I tried a quick search and couldn't find anything) to set the current follower faction (58C4E) ranking to -1.

Alternatively you could try addfac 58c4c (dismissed follower faction).

Also try:
disable
enable

And this might reset the NPC.  I believe there is also a code to completely reset the actor but I can't remember it off the top of my head - but be warned, this resets everything, including their inventory, and they will run around naked for the rest of the game.

A bit long winded but I hope it helps.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I would try killing him, taking a different follower, and then using the "resurrect" command. This tends to do a pretty good job of resetting follower status.